# How can I call contract which created from another contract (In TESTING)?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, contract-deployment, erc-721, testing

Hello guys now Im **testing** my contract, but I dont know how to call contract which created from another contract, If someone did it please help)

Create I mean like following code.

```
    function _createFNftToken(
        string calldata _name, 
        string calldata _symbol, 
        uint256 _amount,
        address _to
    ) private returns(address){
        fNftErc20 fNftErc20Token = new fNftErc20(_name, _symbol, _amount, _to);
        assert(address(fNftErc20Token) != address(0));
        return address(fNftErc20Token);
    }
```

Test code:

```
        it("getFractionalizeParameters(): Must show zero address after user claimNft()", async()=>{
            await tokenNft.mint(accounts[0], 'some/uri', {from: accounts[0]})
            let tokenIdFirst = await tokenNft.totalSupply({from: accounts[0]}) - 1

            // Here created new contract but i dont know how to call it.
            let erc20Address = await tokenFractalization.fractionalizeNft(tokenNft.address, tokenIdFirst, accounts[0], amount, 'Some_name', 'SOME_SYMBOL', {from: accounts[0]})
          
            console.log(await erc20Address.approve(tokenFractalization.address, await erc20Address.totalSupply({from: accounts[0]}), {from: accounts[0]}))
            await tokenFractalization.claimNft(tokenNft.address, tokenIdFirst,  accounts[0], {from: accounts[0]})
            let fNftAddress = await tokenFractalization.getFractionalizeNft(tokenNft.address, tokenIdFirst, {from: accounts[0]});
            let userBalance = await tokenNft.balanceOf(accounts[0], {from: accounts[0]})
            assert.equal(fNftAddress, nullAddress)
            assert.equal(fNftAddress, 0)
            assert.equal(userBalance, 1)
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually the recommended approach is to emit an event with the contract address. Then you can read the event from the transaction receipt and get the address.

```
event TokenCreated(address indexed a);

function _createFNftToken(
    string calldata _name, 
    string calldata _symbol, 
    uint256 _amount,
    address _to
) private returns(address){
    fNftErc20 fNftErc20Token = new fNftErc20(_name, _symbol, _amount, _to);
    emit TokenCreated(address(fNftErc20Token));
    return address(fNftErc20Token);
}
```

Note: Using assert there is redundant, if new fails the whole transaction should revert.